# How to sort by last name and print the new array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So basically, I am creating a phone book with various information such as name, phone number, address, etc.  It is saved using a class.  I need some help sorting this array by last name and then print the new list.

I have tried various sorting methods.  I don't know if the sorting method is working or if I am just printing the array without it being sorted yet.  I created the string last1 and last2 because I was getting an error when just using addressBook[j] into the swap line.  I also tried turning the strings to ascii values to compare.

```
void sortAddressBookByLastName(addressBookType addressBook[], int 
numOfAddress){

string last1, last2;

for (int i = 0; i < numOfAddress-1; i ++){
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfAddress - i - 1; j ++)
    {
        last1=addressBook[j].getLastName();
        last2=addressBook[j+1].getLastName();

        if (last1 > last2){
            swap(last1,last2);
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0; i < numOfAddress;i++){
    addressBook[i].print();
}

}
```

Comment: This is for school assignment and we are supposed to use arrays.  I'm just using what I have been taught so far

Comment: change this `swap(last1,last2);`, to this `swap(addressBook[j],addressBook[j+1]);`, it might work

Comment: I get a "no matching function for call to swap error" :/

Comment: Yes, Ive been taught how to reference but I normally put the reference into the parameter and we were told not to change the parameters of the function

Comment: I see what I have been doing now... I was just swapping the name and not transferring the rest of the data as well.  So i was just adding the name onto the previous persons data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is swapping the local variables `last1` and `last2`; it doesn't change elements of the array.

Comment: I was getting errors when I was putting          
swap(addressBook[j].getLastName(),addressBook[j+1].getLastName());

Comment: @MichaelTorres: yes... you need `swap(addressBook[j], addressBook[j+1])`

Comment: I am a damn idiot... thank you very much.  So i was just changing the name and keeping all the other info of the other people right?!?! lol

Comment: @MichaelTorres: yes :-D ... you were not sorting BY name... you were sorting JUST names; not a very useful operation indeed...